# Trying to grab dates using Python, BeautifulSoup and/or Regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this list:

````
tags = [```<div class="cat-info-index">
<h2><a href="catalogue/lady_standing_at_a_virginal.html">A Lady Standing at a Virginal </a></h2> c. 1670–1674
<br/> Oil on canvas
<br/> 51.7 x 45.2 cm. (20 3/8 x 17 3/4 in.)
<br/>
<a href="museum_pages.html#LONDONNG" target="_blank">National Gallery</a>, London
<br/>
<a href="mailto:info@vermeerdelft.nl">email contact</a>
<br/>
</div>, <div class="cat-info-index">
<h2><a href="catalogue/lady_seated_at_a_virginal.html">A Lady Seated at a Virginal </a></h2> c. 1670–1675
<br/> Oil on canvas
<br/> 51.5 x 45.5 cm. (20 1/4 x 17 7/8 in.)
<br/>
<a href="museum_pages.html#LONDONNG" target="_blank">National Gallery</a>, London
<br/>
<a href="mailto:info@vermeerdelft.nl">email contact</a></div>, <div class="cat-info-index"><h2><a href="catalogue/allegory_of_faith.html">Allegory of Faith</a></h2> c. 1670–1674
<br/> Oil on canvas
<br/> 114.3 x 88.9 cm. (45 x 35 in.)
<br/>
<a href="museum_pages.html#MET" target="_blank">Metropolitan Museum of Art</a>, New York
<br/>
<a href="mailto:communications@metmuseum.org"><em> museum contact</em></a></div>, <div class="cat-info-index">
<h2><a href="catalogue/praxedis.html">Saint Praxedis </a></h2> 1655
<br/> Oil on canvas
<br/> 101.6 x 82.6 cm. (40 x 32 1/2 in.)
<br/> National Museum of Western Art, Tokyo</div>, <div class="cat-info-index">
<h2><a href="catalogue/baron_rolin.html">A Young Woman Seated at the Virginals </a></h2> (attributed to Vermeer)
<br/> Oil on canvas
<br/> c. 1670
<br/> 25.2 x 20 cm. (9 7/8 x 7 7/8 in.)
<br/>
<a href="museumsthree.html#KAPLAN">The Leiden Collection</a>, New York</div>```]
````

HTML:

```html
<div class="cat-info-index">
    <h2><a href="catalogue/lady_standing_at_a_virginal.html">A Lady Standing at a Virginal </a></h2> c. 1670–1674
    <br/> Oil on canvas
    <br/> 51.7 x 45.2 cm. (20 3/8 x 17 3/4 in.)
    <br/>
    <a href="museum_pages.html#LONDONNG" target="_blank">National Gallery</a>, London
    <br/>
    <a href="mailto:info@vermeerdelft.nl">email contact</a>
    <br/>
</div>,
<div class="cat-info-index">
    <h2><a href="catalogue/lady_seated_at_a_virginal.html">A Lady Seated at a Virginal </a></h2> c. 1670–1675
    <br/> Oil on canvas
    <br/> 51.5 x 45.5 cm. (20 1/4 x 17 7/8 in.)
    <br/>
    <a href="museum_pages.html#LONDONNG" target="_blank">National Gallery</a>, London
    <br/>
    <a href="mailto:info@vermeerdelft.nl">email contact</a></div>,
<div class="cat-info-index"><h2><a href="catalogue/allegory_of_faith.html">Allegory of Faith</a></h2> c. 1670–1674
    <br/> Oil on canvas
    <br/> 114.3 x 88.9 cm. (45 x 35 in.)
    <br/>
    <a href="museum_pages.html#MET" target="_blank">Metropolitan Museum of Art</a>, New York
    <br/>
    <a href="mailto:communications@metmuseum.org"><em> museum contact</em></a></div>,
<div class="cat-info-index">
    <h2><a href="catalogue/praxedis.html">Saint Praxedis </a></h2> 1655
    <br/> Oil on canvas
    <br/> 101.6 x 82.6 cm. (40 x 32 1/2 in.)
    <br/> National Museum of Western Art, Tokyo
</div>,
<div class="cat-info-index">
    <h2><a href="catalogue/baron_rolin.html">A Young Woman Seated at the Virginals </a></h2> (attributed to Vermeer)
    <br/> Oil on canvas
    <br/> c. 1670
    <br/> 25.2 x 20 cm. (9 7/8 x 7 7/8 in.)
    <br/>
    <a href="museumsthree.html#KAPLAN">The Leiden Collection</a>, New York
</div>
```

I want to grab:

['1670–1674', '1670-1675', '1655', '1670']

I've tried regex, but can only seem to either grab the date ranges with a dash or the stand alone year dates. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share that as formatted HTML? It's tough to read.

Comment: Also, it's not clear what you are after exactly. Can you edit your question with the exact desired output?

Comment: we need a formated HTML plz - this is pretty bad reading - help us to help you. Thanks in advance -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """<div class="cat-info-index">
    <h2><a href="catalogue/lady_standing_at_a_virginal.html">A Lady Standing at a Virginal </a></h2> c. 1670–1674
    <br/> Oil on canvas
    <br/> 51.7 x 45.2 cm. (20 3/8 x 17 3/4 in.)
    <br/>
    <a href="museum_pages.html#LONDONNG" target="_blank">National Gallery</a>, London
    <br/>
    <a href="mailto:info@vermeerdelft.nl">email contact</a>
    <br/>
</div>,
<div class="cat-info-index">
    <h2><a href="catalogue/lady_seated_at_a_virginal.html">A Lady Seated at a Virginal </a></h2> c. 1670–1675
    <br/> Oil on canvas
    <br/> 51.5 x 45.5 cm. (20 1/4 x 17 7/8 in.)
    <br/>
    <a href="museum_pages.html#LONDONNG" target="_blank">National Gallery</a>, London
    <br/>
    <a href="mailto:info@vermeerdelft.nl">email contact</a></div>,
<div class="cat-info-index"><h2><a href="catalogue/allegory_of_faith.html">Allegory of Faith</a></h2> c. 1670–1674
    <br/> Oil on canvas
    <br/> 114.3 x 88.9 cm. (45 x 35 in.)
    <br/>
    <a href="museum_pages.html#MET" target="_blank">Metropolitan Museum of Art</a>, New York
    <br/>
    <a href="mailto:communications@metmuseum.org"><em> museum contact</em></a></div>,
<div class="cat-info-index">
    <h2><a href="catalogue/praxedis.html">Saint Praxedis </a></h2> 1655
    <br/> Oil on canvas
    <br/> 101.6 x 82.6 cm. (40 x 32 1/2 in.)
    <br/> National Museum of Western Art, Tokyo
</div>,
<div class="cat-info-index">
    <h2><a href="catalogue/baron_rolin.html">A Young Woman Seated at the Virginals </a></h2> (attributed to Vermeer)
    <br/> Oil on canvas
    <br/> c. 1670
    <br/> 25.2 x 20 cm. (9 7/8 x 7 7/8 in.)
    <br/>
    <a href="museumsthree.html#KAPLAN">The Leiden Collection</a>, New York
</div>"""
l = []
for h2 in soup.find_all('h2'):
    l.append(h2.next_sibling.strip())
l
```